# Backspace in insert abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations

To work, abbreviations need to be separated by whitespace.  E.g., if I have an `iab fo FOOBAR` then typing `whatfo` will not trigger the abbreviation.  There are some obvious sensible reasons for this.

However, I'd like an abbreviation that could be used as a suffix without me having to trigger the iab then go back and remove the space.  Is this possible? E.g., `iab fo <backspace>FOOBAR`.

Comment: Does the following code produce what you want? http://vpaste.net/IfU1j

Comment: @saginaw Yeah, brilliant -- post that as an answer and it's yours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write inside your vimrc: `iab fo <BS>FOOBAR`

`<BS>` is the notation to use for the backspace key.

For more information about special key names, see:

```
:help key-notation
```

Comment: The "simpler way" didn't work out in this case because I think of robustness; the actual suffix is `[7:0]` and you would have to play around with the number of `b`s, etc. to customize for that, I think.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever You are right, I didn't think about that. In this particular case, maybe replacing `b` and `e` with `B` and `E` would be enough. But there may be other cases where it would fail, I don't know. In any case the first version should, hopefully, work most of the time.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever Rereading my answer I realize that it's overly complex. Probably something like `iab fo <BS>foobar` was enough. Sorry for the inconvenience, you should probably tick the answer of @djjcast as the correct answer. At the moment I can't remove my answer, but once I can I will. Again really sorry, I'm not used to abbreviations.

Comment: Hey `<BS>` was just the thing.  I swear tried something like that, but I don't know all the control characters, so I might have used `<backspace>` or something.

Comment: Christian Brabandt had a good suggestion too about using snippets (did not stop to think you could place the parameter in front...) -- maybe I will put both those into a simple alternative answer.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever I understand, no problem. If you want to see all the special key names, you can read them here: `:help key-notation`

Answer (score 4):

Simply press in insert mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>. This will trigger abbreviations to be expanded, without entering a space

Comment: You misread the question.  I want the end result to be something like: `X(FOOBAR)` not `X( FOOBAR`.  Using Ctrl-] just eliminates the space *at the end*.  I need to be able to use the abbreviation -- *which also depends on whitespace at the beginning to fire* -- but have it concatenated with the *previous* word (that's what a "**suffix**" means).

Comment: Oh, you want a snippet plugin...

Comment: I guess this could be done with something defined `${1}FOOBAR` -- that's a good answer.  If you want to change this :/ or add another answer I'll tick that.

Comment: since i personally don't know snippet plugins, I can't seriously make this an answer.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, here's a way to define and expand abbreviations that expand anywhere:

```
let s:anywhere_abbreviations = {
    \ 'fo': 'FOOBAR',
    \ 'ab': 'ABBREVIATION',
\ }

function! s:MaybeExpandAbbreviation(trigger)
    for key in keys(s:anywhere_abbreviations)
        if matchstr(getline('.'), repeat('.', strchars(key)) . '\%' . col('.') . 'c') ==# key
            return repeat("\<BS>", strchars(key)) . s:anywhere_abbreviations[key] . a:trigger
        endif
    endfor
    return "\<C-]>" . a:trigger
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <Space> <SID>MaybeExpandAbbreviation("\<Space>")
```

Just add the abbreviations that should expand anywhere to the `s:anywhere_abbreviations` dictionary. The `s:MaybeExpandAbbreviation()` function searches for and expands abbreviation matches when the trigger key is pressed - `<Space>` is mapped to trigger the expansion of the "anywhere abbreviations".

With the above `s:anywhere_abbreviations` dictionary, typing `whatfo<Space>` will expand to `whatFOOBAR`.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the two simplest answers that came out of this:

1. **You can use a backspace directly in an abbreviation** -- various special characters are documented under `:help keycodes`.  So, e.g.:

   ```
   :iab cdt <BS>cedental
   ```

   Will allow you to type `trans cdt` and get `transcendental`.
2. One I'm particularly ashamed of since I've been using it for years: The common [snipMate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) allows for parameters to go in front, so

   ```
    snippet cdt
        ${1}cendental ${2}
   ```

   Allows for typing `cdt`, which <kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand to `cendental` and put the cursor in front so you can type `trans`, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to move to the beginning of the next word.