# vim insert abbreviation with text in front of the map

Tags: abbreviations

Is there an option to make vim expand an abbreviaiation at the end of a word?
In other words let's say I map `:iab bb bar`, how can I get the expansion:

`foobb<space>` = `foobar`?

Comment: This answer might help: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6400/6960 With this code, if you type `foofo<space>`, it will be expanded into `fooFOOBAR`. All you would have to do, is put your abbreviations inside the dictionary `s:anywhere_abbreviations`. For example, to add your abbreviation `iab bb bar`, you would add in the dictionary `'bb': 'bar'`.