# Something like iabbrev that works in the middle of words?

Tags: filetype-tex, abbreviations

In LaTeX the `\ldots` command is used to make an ellipsis, so I wanted something like `iabbrev ... \ldots` that would work in the middle of words, so `whatever...` would become `whatever\ldots`.

Any ideas?

Comment: A map might work: `inoremap ... \ldots`. Since one of the main benefits of abbreviations is Vim avoiding middle-of-word expansions, I suppose this qualifies for a map.

Comment: [This](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/backspace-in-insert-abbreviation) question may come in handy.

Comment: @muru Ah, for some reason a regular `inoremap` isn't working for me, but now I tried it with `vim -u NONE` and it works perfectly, so it must be some plugin messing things up. Thanks! And thank you for the link, @jair, if I can't work it out with `inoremap` I'll go with one of those options.

Comment: Maybe a snippet would be interesting? With [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/tree/1c6b4f75a006c4411d01a1234cabda3eb4aded1a) for example, you can define a snippet active only in latex buffer, when you enter a predefined text (e.g. `ld`) and press a predefined key the entered text will expand to whatever you want. It requires a little bit of configuration but it is pretty flexible and you can make it expand in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want an abbreviation rather than a mapping, a compromise would be an end-id abbreviation (see `:h abbreviations`). These end in a keyword character, but the other characters in the abbreviation must be non-keyword characters. These will expand directly after a keyword character. So you could do:

```
:iabbrev ..s \ldots
```

Then, typing `'whatever..s '` will be expanded to `'whatever\ldots '`

One benefit of this is that `...` won't be expanded when you don't want it to be.